# How to make the scroll count reach the last element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the count take into account the last photo. At the moment it stops at 16/17.

When I try to add hH = $('h2' * 2).outerHeight(). the counting gets all messed up even though it reaches 17.

https://codepen.io/Design_Lover/pen/OKQyKM

I would like the count to reach 17 instead of stopping at 16

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.work').scroll(function() {
    var $this = $('h2');
    $('.image').each(function() {
      var hT = $(this).offset().top,
        hH = $('h2').outerHeight(),
        wH = $('.work').height(),
        wS = $this.scrollTop();
      console.log((hT - wH), wS);
      if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        $('#count').text($(this).data('index'));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems an index error. It is working if I add `<h2 class="image" data-index="0"></h2>
                <h2 class="image" data-index="1"><img src="https://media.architecturaldigest.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Indian-minimalism_041.jpg"></h2>
`

Comment: oh thank you, what should I have put instead ? @mplungjan

Comment: Sorry. I thought image was the image and not the h2. Anyway, I see the first offset is halfway down the second image. So perhaps adding an empty h2 is the quickest solution

Comment: @mplungjan no unfortunately that did not work

Comment: It did in your codepen

Comment: do I have to add it at the end? because when I do I have to add 3 empty h2?

Comment: In front as I showed just one empty one with index 0

Comment: @mplungjan THANK YOU, it worked

Comment: It’s not the best solution but the fastest